# Sip call library options for react native app developer?

Tags: react-native, sip, pjsip, react-native-voice

I am planning to develop a react native app that support sip call and wish some suggestion on which library to choose and feasibility. I had developed in native android app using PJsip, but being a new react native app developer, wish to seek some suggestions from experienced developer.

Few npm packages I notice for sip call

[react-native-sip](https://stackoverflow.com)

React-native-sip-pjsip

[react-native-jssip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jssip)

Right now I have started developing using  react-native-sip.,but since such sip call development is time consuming and package require a long lasting updates and community. I would highly appreciate for any suggestion.